# Regex to search all files that does not contain an id in button tags

Tags: regex, bash, grep

I don't know regex and use it rarely. I'm trying to identify html button tags without ids. Searching I ended up with this

```
$ grep -Prn '<button(.*)(?!\id)(.*)>' .

but search results came with <button ... id ...>. Like

<button id="criar_rascunho" class="botao-editar botao-claro" onclick="editarConteudoRoteiro('<?php echo $roteiro_versao->getId(); ?>','<?php echo $roteiro_release->getId(); ?>')">

<button class="botao-claro botao-progresso" data-titulo="<?php echo $disciplinaOfertaGrupo['disciplinaOferta']->getNome();?>" data-dofid="<?php echo $disciplinaOfertaGrupo['disciplinaOferta']->getId(); ?>"><?php echo $this->translate('ver-progresso'); ?></button>

<button class="excluir-disciplina excluir-disciplina-icones"></button></td>
```

in other words, both

```
<button ... >
```

and

```
<button ... id ...>
```

are in the search results.

Comment: Please note that using regular expressions to parse HTML is a losing battle.  It may work in some situations, but fail in many others, not least of which is if the `<button>` tag is on two different lines.  See http://htmlparsing.com/regexes.html for other examples of where your regexes may fall down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the below.

```
grep -Prn '<button\b(?![^>]*\bid\b)[^>]*>'
```

`(?![^>]*\bid\b)` negative lookahead which asserts that the match `<button` won't be followed by `id` substring within the tag itself.

**Example:**

```
$ cat file
<button ... >
<button ...  id >
$ grep -Prn '<button\b(?![^>]*\bid\b)[^>]*>' file
1:<button ... >
```

Comment: This fails to match "<button name = 'id'>" and similar tags containing "id" as a word, but not as an attribute name.

Comment: @JohnBollinger posted according to his regex he tried. You could try `grep -Prn '<button\b(?![^>]*\bid\b *=)[^>]*>'`

Comment: This fails for multiline elements such as `<button \n name="...">`.

Answer (score 1):

It can shortly be done without using look aheads as

```
grep -v '<button[^>]*id.*>'
```

from `man grep`

> -v, --invert-match
>                 Invert the sense of matching, to select non-matching lines.  (-v
>                 is specified by POSIX.)

**Test**

```
$ cat input
<button ... >
<button ...  id >

$ grep -v '<button[^>]*id.*>' input
<button ... >
```

---

If you still wish to use look aheads, all you need to change the *anything before id* into the look ahead as well like

```
grep -P '<button(?![^>]*id)'
```

**Test**

```
$ cat input
<button ... >
<button ...  id >

$ grep -P '<button(?![^>]*id)' input
<button ... >
```

Comment: The regex presented is not precise enough.  It will fail to match tags with attribute values containing the substring "id", even though they have no "id" attribute.  Also tags with bearing the attribute "formnovalidate", but no "id" attribute.  Not to mention non-standard attributes.

Answer (score 1):

Regex is not a very good tool for parsing [X]HTML.  It is impossible to do it correctly unless you make simplifying assumptions about the form of the input, and even then it's hard.  You would be much better off using a *bona fide* parser.

Also, regex is not a single thing, but rather a family of things.  The regex language(s) handled by POSIX `grep` are different from the one handled by Perl, which is slightly different from the one handled by Java, which is different from the one handled by Javascript, etc..  I'd just talk about `grep`'s dialect, but ....

Moreover, `grep` is a line-oriented tool, whereas HTML is not a line-oriented language.  That is an unsolvable mismatch unless you are willing to assume that your button elements will never span multiple lines, like this:

```
<button
  id='my_id' />
```

Furthermore, since `grep` is, again, a *line*-oriented tool, even if you had a regex that worked, it would match lines containing two or more `<button>` elements where some had `id` attributes and others didn't.  That could be confusing.

In a general sense, for a pattern matcher to do the job correctly, it must match whole tags, including every attribute in those tags, in a way that disallows any of the attributes from having the name 'id'.  It must be certain to avoid considering substrings that span two or more tags, and it must not exclude tags where the substring "id" appears as anything other than a complete attribute name.

This monster of a Perl regex (since you are using `grep -P`) would be more accurate than what you presented:

```
<button(?:\s+(?:(?!id)[A-Za-z0-9.-]+|id[A-Za-z0-9.-]+)(?:\s*=\s*(?:[^ \t\n\r>'"]+|'[^']*'|"[^"]*")))*\s*/?>
```

It matches one complete HTML start tag or empty tag (it is not fooled by multiple tags on the same line) where none of the attributes, if any, are named exactly "id".  It will not be fooled by three-character or longer attribute names that contain "id" as a substring, nor by "id" appearing in attribute values.  If you want mixed-case matching, then that could be added without too much additional difficulty.

On the other hand, it will also match character data that mimics a button start or empty tag without an id, and when used with `grep` it will fail to match any button start tag that spans more than one line.  It will also fail to match valid start tags if they contain attribute names with characters that are neither (unaccented) Latin letters, nor digits, nor '.', nor '-'.  It may have other shortcomings.